# Ahk: run a python script with args

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, autohotkey, sys

I have seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6135238/3154274) (and many others) but I am still not able to retrieve the args in python.

1) With this...

```
Run Cmd \k "Python  C:\my.py %myvar%"
```

... a Cmd is open but nothing happens : my.py isn't started.

2) With this...

```
Run C:\my1.py %myvar%
```

... the python script is run but when I retrieve the args with `sys.argv`, I only get the path of the script not `myvar`.  Len(sys.arg) return 1 so myvar isn't passed down to python.

Comment: `sys.argv[0] will be your script path, your argument should be from sys.argv[1]
`

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is %myvar% provided that there aren't spaces

Comment: @pyd @ Jean-François Fabre, thanks for that and sorry for not being more precise. `len(sys.arg)` returns 1,  I don't have a `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: seems that your association with .py files is broken (registry issue). You should repair your python installation. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434689/need-ot-use-a-batch-file-or-power-shell-to-set-a-file-extension-to-a-program

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, sys.arg works when I start my python script directly in CMD with the args with `python C:\myscript.py sometext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/121831-send-text-to-cmdexe-window-and-execute/) solved it.

```
commands=
(join&
 python "C:\my.py" "%myvar%"`n
)
Run, cmd /c %commands%  
return
```

It's also possible to use `Run, cmd /k %commands%`    or `Run,%comspec% /k %commands%`