# Call python function with arguments and get returned value in autohotkey

Tags: python, autohotkey

I have a python script called "server.py" and inside it I have a function `def calcFunction(arg1):  ...  return output` How can I call the function calcFunction with arguments and use the return value in autohotkey? This is what I want to do in autohotkey:

```
ToSend = someString ; a string
output = Run server.py, calcFunction(ToSend) ; get the returned value from the function with ToSend as argument
Send, output ; use the returned value in autohotkey
```

I have looked online but nothing seems to fully answer my question. Can it even be done?

Comment: I think you may need to make your Python script **`print()`** it's output.

Comment: I have solved similar problems by writing the results to a TXT file if that interests you.

Comment: Can you just use StdOut in the python function?  Then run the python script in a wscript shell returning the StdOut value to ahk . . .  Easy, peasy.  & no need to write to files or clipboard, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send your parameters to Python, you could use arguments from within your Python script. You can do this with the `sys` library:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0]) # name of file
print(sys.argv[1]) # first argument
print(sys.argv[2]) # second argument...
```

From within your AutoHotKey script, you can send parameters to the Python script by adding them as arguments right after specifying the file name:

```
RunWait, server.py "This will be printed as the first argument!" "This is the second!"
```

Then, to get the output of the function back to AHK, you could use `sys` again by utilizing it's `exit()` function:

```
sys.exit(EXIT_NUMBER)
```

And back in AHK, you recieve the `EXIT_NUMBER` inside the variable `ErrorLevel`.
Put all together, your code should look something like this:

```
; AHK
RunWait, server.py "%ToSend%"

# Python
sys.exit(calcFunction(sys.argv[1]))

; AHK
MsgBox %ErrorLevel%
```

Comment: Getting the errorcode (python's EXIT_NUMBER) is not quite the same as getting the result of the server.py function operating on "ToSend."

Comment: That is true, an alternative would be to have python dump the return value into a file, and when the program exits, AHK can read that file. In my answer, I was assuming that the return statement is an integer, which I guess makes it partially invalid.

Answer (score 2):

using python COM server, ahk can really calls python functions. directly.
you use it like this: `MsgBox % pythonComServer.toUppercase("hello world")`

simple example: return uppercased string
use the python part from [How to program hotstrings in python like in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780086/how-to-program-hotstrings-in-python-like-in-autohotkey/65783573#65783573) and use this for ahk part:

call python function uppercase.ahk

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance, force
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetBatchLines, -1
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off

pythonComServer:=ComObjCreate("Python.stringUppercaser")
;or
; pythonComServer:=ComObjCreate("{C70F3BF7-2947-4F87-B31E-9F5B8B13D24F}") ;use your own CLSID

MsgBox % pythonComServer.toUppercase("hello world")
Exitapp

f3::Exitapp
```

customized version: (math) use [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) to simplify Expression 
read this first to understand: [How to program hotstrings in python like in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780086/how-to-program-hotstrings-in-python-like-in-autohotkey/65783573#65783573)

sympy com server.py

```py
from sympy import simplify, Number, N
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

from decimal import Decimal

from winsound import MessageBeep

transformations = standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application, convert_xor)

def removeTrailingZerosFromNum(num):
    dec = Decimal(str(num))

    tup = dec.as_tuple()
    delta = len(tup.digits) + tup.exponent
    digits = ''.join(str(d) for d in tup.digits)
    if delta <= 0:
        zeros = abs(tup.exponent) - len(tup.digits)
        val = '0.' + ('0' * zeros) + digits
    else:
        val = digits[:delta] + ('0' * tup.exponent) + '.' + digits[delta:]
    val = val.rstrip('0')
    if val[-1] == '.':
        val = val[:-1]
    if tup.sign:
        return '-' + val
    return val


def removeTrailingZerosFromExpr(operatorObject):
    if operatorObject.args:
        return type(operatorObject)(*[removeTrailingZerosFromExpr(i) for i in operatorObject.args])
    else:
        try:
            return Number(removeTrailingZerosFromNum(operatorObject))
        except:
            return operatorObject

def removeTrailingZerosFromExprOrNumber(operatorObject):
    try:
        return removeTrailingZerosFromNum(operatorObject)
    except:
        return removeTrailingZerosFromExpr(operatorObject)

class BasicServer:
    # list of all method names exposed to COM
    _public_methods_ = ["parExprN"]

    @staticmethod
    def parExprN(clipBak):
        parsed = parse_expr(clipBak, transformations=transformations)
        simplified = simplify(N(parsed))
        finalStr = str(removeTrailingZerosFromExprOrNumber(simplified))
        MessageBeep(-1)
        return finalStr.replace("**", "^")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Error: need to supply arg (""--register"" or ""--unregister"")")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        import win32com.server.register
        import win32com.server.exception

        # this server's CLSID
        # NEVER copy the following ID 
        # Use "print(pythoncom.CreateGuid())" to make a new one.
        myClsid="{4530C817-6C66-46C8-8FB0-E606970A8DF6}"
        # this server's (user-friendly) program ID, can be anything you want
        myProgID="Python.SimplifyExpr"
        
        import ctypes
        def make_sure_is_admin():
            try:
                if ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin():
                    return
            except:
                pass
            exit("YOU MUST RUN THIS AS ADMIN")

        if sys.argv[1] == "--register":
            make_sure_is_admin()

            import pythoncom
            import os.path
            realPath = os.path.realpath(__file__)
            dirName = os.path.dirname(realPath)
            nameOfThisFile = os.path.basename(realPath)
            nameNoExt = os.path.splitext(nameOfThisFile)[0]
            # stuff will be written here
            # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\${myClsid}
            # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{c2467d33-71c5-4057-977c-e847c2286882}
            # and here
            # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\${myProgID}
            # HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Python.SimplifyExpr
            win32com.server.register.RegisterServer(
                clsid=myClsid,
                # I guess this is {fileNameNoExt}.{className}
                pythonInstString=nameNoExt + ".BasicServer", #sympy com server.BasicServer
                progID=myProgID,
                # optional description
                desc="(math) SymPy simplify Expression",
                #we only want the registry key LocalServer32
                #we DO NOT WANT InProcServer32: pythoncom39.dll, NO NO NO
                clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                #this is needed if this file isn't in PYTHONPATH: it tells regedit which directory this file is located
                #this will write HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{4530C817-6C66-46C8-8FB0-E606970A8DF6}\PythonCOMPath : dirName
                addnPath=dirName,
            )
            print("Registered COM server.")
            # don't use UseCommandLine(), as it will write InProcServer32: pythoncom39.dll
            # win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(BasicServer)
        elif sys.argv[1] == "--unregister":
            make_sure_is_admin()

            print("Starting to unregister...")

            win32com.server.register.UnregisterServer(myClsid, myProgID)

            print("Unregistered COM server.")
        else:
            print("Error: arg not recognized")
```

to register:
`python "sympy com server.py" --register`


sympy com client.ahk

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#SingleInstance, force
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetBatchLines, -1
#KeyHistory 0
ListLines Off

sympyComServer:=ComObjCreate("Python.SimplifyExpr")
;or
; pythonComServer:=ComObjCreate("{4530C817-6C66-46C8-8FB0-E606970A8DF6}") ;use your own CLSID

; clipboard:=sympyComServer.parExprN("1+3*7")
clipboard:=sympyComServer.parExprN("1/3 + 1/2")

$#s::
clipboard:=sympyComServer.parExprN(clipboard)
return

f3::Exitapp
```