# how to register a 64bit python COM server

Tags: python, 64-bit, autohotkey, pywin32

ahk code:
`ComObjCreate("{C2474B5A-5E9D-484D-BDFD-20A100183426}")`

this works in AutoHotkeyU32.exe, but not in AutoHotkeyU64.exe
error message is: `the specified module could not be found.`

full code is here: [How to program hotstrings in python like in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780086/how-to-program-hotstrings-in-python-like-in-autohotkey/65783573#65783573)

I call my SymPy functions using ahk hotkeys. I register the python script as a COM server using pywin32 and load it using ahk.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need pywin32, but don't download using `pip install pywin32`
download from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases
OR ELSE IT WON'T WORK for AutoHotkeyU64.exe, it will only work for AutoHotkeyU32.exe.
make sure to download amd64, (I downloaded pywin32-300.win-amd64-py3.8.exe)

EDIT: now I understand why it didn't work
I think it CAN work when using `pip install pywin32` if you register it correctly.
you have 2 choices:

1. register it correctly as shown here [How to program hotstrings in python like in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65780086/how-to-program-hotstrings-in-python-like-in-autohotkey/65783573#65783573) :
   do NOT use `UseCommandLine()`, use `RegisterServer(clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, ...)`
2. after server has been registed using `UseCommandLine()`, delete the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{C70F3BF7-2947-4F87-B31E-9F5B8B13D24F}\PythonCOMPath\InprocServer32`

   replace `{C70F3BF7-2947-4F87-B31E-9F5B8B13D24F}` with your own `CLSID`

(I think) there is no need for 
key: `InprocServer32`:
`Name` : `(Default)`
`Type` : `REG_EXPAND_SZ`
`Data` : `pythoncom39.dll`, 
also, requiring it makes it fail

(I think) There's no need because it actually uses LocalServer32 (which is also a key)
mine is:
`Name` : `(Default)`
`Type` : `REG_SZ`
`Data` : `C:\PROGRA~3\Miniconda3\pythonw.exe "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\server\localserver.py" {C70F3BF7-2947-4F87-B31E-9F5B8B13D24F}`

`localserver.py` is the one doing the COM stuff, to prove it, replace `pythonw` with `python`. you will the window when it's ran.